# How to sample random datapoints from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset X in panda dataframe with about 48000 datapoints. In the dataset here is a feature called gender, 1 representing male and 0 representing female.
How do I sample entries from my original dataset? Say I want a new dataset Y with 1000 random datapoint samples from X with 700 males and 300 females? I came up with this simple algorithm but cant figure out why it isn't working

```
def Sample(X,maleSize,femalesize):
 DD=X
 for i in  range(len(DD)):
    if (DD.race[i]==1.0)&(DD.gender.sum()==maleSize):
        DD=DD.drop(i)

    if (DD.race[i]==0.0) & ((len(DD)-DD.gender.sum())>femalesize):
           DD=DD.drop(i) 
return DD
```

Comment: Try separating the data into two dataframes, one for males and one for females, then use the Pandas method `.sample()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html. If you really want to stick with your method, the first thing I notice is you use `&` when you should be using `and`.

Comment: There is not random factor in your code so far. If you are training a model, you can use StratifiedShuffleSplit to do that.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I've never heard of StratifiedShuffleSplit, but I just looked it up and it looks like it is used to randomly split the data. But it looks like Tiana wants the data to be split by male/female, which is not random. Is there a way to make StratifiedShuffleSplit compatible with a known split?

Comment: Hi @AdamOppenheimer, as I said. I feel like this is for training a model. But your approach is nice.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos If you look at the parameters for the function Tiana wrote, it includes `maleSize` and `femaleSize`, so the intention is to be choosing a fixed number of males and a fixed number of females. Even if it is for training a model, the way the data is split is not random, the draws after the split are where the randomness is introduced.

Comment: Can you fix the identation of your sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
males = X[X['gender']==1].sample(n=700)
females = X[X['gender']==0].sample(n=300)
ndf = males.append(females).sample(frac=1)
```

Or:

```
weights = [.7 if x==1 else .3 for x in X['gender']]
X.sample(n=1000, weights = weights)
```

Comment: I can't make the edit, but `=` should be `==` for checking the gender. Also, why do you have the `.sample()` at the end?

Comment: I just want to make sure you see the edit I made to my comment: why do you have the `.sample(frac=1)` at the end?

Comment: I shuffled the data after appending.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Thanks for the response. Also, you could probably generate the weights for your second method faster with `weights = 0.7 * (X['gender'] == 1) + 0.3 * (X['gender'] == 0)`, since it is vectorized